# Do I need a deleter for shared_ptr to free memory allocated by an allocator?

Tags: c++, memory, stl

I want use shared_ptr to manage dynamically allocated arrays. Before I learnt the existence of STL allocator, I always used new[] to allocate memory and write a deleter for shared_ptr to free it. The code then would look like:

```
struct ArrayDeleter
{
   void operator()(int* p) { delete [] p; }
};
...
...
std::shared_ptr<int> array(new int[100], ArrayDeleter());
...
```

Without the ArrayDeleter to free memory, tools like valgrind will report memory error for unbalanced new[] and delete[]. I understand this problem is caused by shared_ptr calling `delete` instead of `delete[]` to free the memory.

However, I wonder if it is the same case for memory allocated by an allocator. I had my code look like:

```
std::allocator<int> alloc;
std::shared_ptr<int> array(alloc.allocate(10));
...
```

So no specific deleter is provided in the code. Then I checked the program using valgrind, but this time, it didn't complain anything. So can I safely assume std::allocator is implemented to use `new` to allocate memory, so that the default `delete` operator used by std::shared_ptr is fine with it?

What about I implemented my own allocators? Am I right that a customised allocator that doesn't use new operator will break the above code, i.e I still need a deleter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I safely assume std::allocator is implemented to use new to
>   allocate memory, so that the default delete operator used by
>   std::shared_ptr is fine with it?

No, you cannot. The default `std::allocator<T>` is defined to allocate the memory using global `::operator new`, but I don't think it's required that each call to `allocate` results in exactly one call to `::operator new`, or that the value returned from `allocate()` is equal to the value returned from `new`.

The correct way to free the memory is by calling `deallocate()` on the allocator, which will use global `::operator delete`.

So, your code is not freeing the data correctly. It just happens to work in your implementation that `std::allocator` isn't doing anything special with the allocations, and that calling `delete` on an `int*` behaves the same as calling global operator `delete`. It could fail for other types or on other implementations.

Also, `allocate()` does not initialize the objects, so calling `delete` would call the destructor for some memory that was never constructed. This has undefined behavior if the type is not trivial (`int` is trivial, though).

Your code is not necessarily correct for custom allocators either, for the same reasons.